# why does sqlcl replace "CAST" when pasting a <tab>

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

SQLcl: Release 21.4

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Version 19.15.0.0.0

When pasting a query into SQLcl I noticed a strange behaviour, when my query that executed fine in DBeaver had a syntax error in SQLcl. The problem is caused by auto replace of `<tab>`.

My query had a part like this:

```
“select case
<tab> when…”
```

when pasted into SQLcl it magically becomes:

```
“select case
cast when…”
```

Even stranger, when you enter “select case” in SQLcl and hit `<tab>` it will replace your case with CAST.

Is it a bug or is it a feature?

Comment: Sounds like it's auto-completing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 22.2...

Comment: quite likely that it is auto-completing, but then it is likely a bug, since CASE is valid at this place. I will try to reproduce this with 22.2.